# How can I add an xml configuration file to a docker image via a Dockerfile?

Tags: docker

I built a .jar file that accesses an .xml file

I add this jar file to docker via a Dockerfile

But how do I add this xml file to the docker image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ADD test-harness.xml test-harness.xml

This basically adds the .xml file to the Docker image and makes it accessible to the jar file which was added in a similar way.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Dockerfile best practices, the COPY command is preferred on the ADD command:

> Although ADD and COPY are functionally similar, generally speaking, COPY is preferred.

recommended reading for your task:

1. The "[ADD or COPY](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#add-or-copy)" section in the Dockerfile best practices.
2. [Docker Tip #2: The Difference between COPY and ADD in a Dockerfile](https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/docker-tip-2-the-difference-between-copy-and-add-in-a-dockerile)